# How do I proceed with Git push without putting my account information every time?

Tags: git

It's a tiring job to type my ID and password every time I want to push something. How can I proceed it globally without putting in my ID, password, not just one repository if possible?

If not, can I push it without that process at least in one repository?

Comment: Use ssh keys; adapt this guide to your workplace's system: https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this command:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

This is actually caching your passwords, so you will not have to enter them every time.

Nevertheless, mind this is not safe if you want to do it on a server with *SSH*. You can see [the related GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) for more details.